# How to optimize for dividing a constant dividend?

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization, integer-division

Optimization for **divided by** a constant is well optimized by gcc, as is well known :)

Now I wonder how **dividing** a constant is optimized. gcc does not help me out, and so does clang.

Maybe I am not good at searching such information, but I cannot find a material about optimization for **dividing constant**. (In contrast, **division by constant** is well introduced.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int x)
{
    // can I optimize off the idiv opcode here?
    return 33659/x;
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("%d", f(x));
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIVIDEND 33

void f ( unsigned int* arr, int n )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n ; i++ )
    {
        arr[i] = DIVIDEND / arr[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int n = 1024;
    unsigned int buf[n];
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        scanf ( "%u", buf + i );
    }
    f ( buf, n );
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf ( "%d", buf[i] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Optimized with `clang -O3 -march=native div.c -o div` only unrolls the loop, whilst:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIVIDEND 33
#define DIVISOR DIVIDEND

void f ( unsigned int* arr, int n )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n ; i++ )
    {
        //arr[i] = DIVIDEND / arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[i] / DIVISOR;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int n = 1024;
    unsigned int buf[n];
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        scanf ( "%u", buf + i );
    }
    f ( buf, n );
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf ( "%d", buf[i] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

using the same command line will yield a pile of terrifying AVX2 code. (Remember that division by constant is rewritten into shift+mul+add, which can be vectorized!)

EDIT2:
Thank @user2722968 ! Applying RCPPS will make the program faster.

Here is my experimental implementation using RCPPS for fast constant-dividend division:

https://github.com/ThinerDAS/didactic-spoon/blob/master/div.c

However, I am not sure how to make it more accurate without large overhead.

Comment: Neither gcc nor clang showing  any optimizations is a good hint that this can in fact not be optimized very well (or at all).

Comment: It would be interesting to know what optimisations OP thinks might be possible in this case.

Comment: I think that -no- optimization is possible.

Comment: The  are optimizing it if the dividend is 0 :P. I think that's the only case that can be optimized.

Comment: @PSkocik the 1/x may be worth of optimization too. But anyway, I can imagine possible optimizations if the `x` is constrained enough, like [1, ... 10] only, etc.

Comment: The only optimisation is to declare/define the function as `static` , allowing it to be inlined.

Comment: With [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) different compilers can be tried and no optimizations are observed.

Answer (score 1):

If you can trigger a really good optimization for "divided by" then you might benefit from computing the reciprocal of `x/33659` using the RCPPS instruction (which does use SSE/AVX).

Comment: RCPPS is a good hint! This instruction is a very rough approximation, and is not reliable, however it is very fast. Hard to trigger the instruction :( I will try it out.