# Computing 2¹²⁸ % uint64_t

Tags: c, assembly, optimization, integer-division

How to efficiently compute 2¹²⁸ % n, where n is `uint64_t` (and non-zero)?

If I had access to a narrowing division like `_udiv128` intrinsic of MSVC I could do:

```
uint64_t remainder;
_udiv128(1, 0, n, &remainder);
_udiv128(remainder, 0, n, &remainder);
```

But that's two slow instructions, not to mention there are CPUs like ARM which do not have the narrowing division. Is there a better way?

Related: [How to compute 2⁶⁴/n in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565537/how-to-compute-2%e2%81%b6%e2%81%b4-n-in-c)

Comment: unfortunately you can optimize division by a constant but not the case where dividend is a constant. If it's too slow then you're probably doing lots of divisions like that and should optimize with SIMD and multithreading. There's a [library for optimizing that called libdivide](https://libdivide.com/)

Comment: in some cases you can utilize the reciprocal instruction in ARM and x86 though: [How to optimize for dividing constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44862898/995714)

Comment: Have you looked at the `libdivide` library? I think this section could be useful: https://github.com/ridiculousfish/libdivide/blob/3bd34388573681ce563348cdf04fe15d24770d04/libdivide.h#L467

Comment: @JosephWood AFAIK, `libdivide` is good only when we compute `a%b` and `b` is a constant but here `a` is the constant, not `b` (at least, it is not specified and it would be unexpected since the result can be precomputed at compile-time in that case).

Comment: @JérômeRichard: The libdivide library is intended to provide, via its API, optimizations for repeated divisions by the same divisor, but Joseph Wood did not point to API information but specifically to source code for a routine that divides a 128-bit number by a 64-bit number. I think the intent there may be that the source code contains some useful information that could be adapted to this problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, that's exactly what I meant. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: related: [How to divide 2¹²⁸ - 1 by a 64-bit divisor, where I only need the 64 LSBs of the quotient?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70051781/995714)

Comment: Have you benchmarked that code and seen that it is too slow for your purpose? (This is the obligatory premature optimization comment)

Answer (score 8):

The number of narrowing divisions can be reduced to 1 with a simple trick:

```
uint64_t remainder;
_udiv128(-n % n, 0, n, &remainder);
```

`-n % n` still costs a 64-bit division, but a division where the high half of the dividend is zero tends to be more efficient (certainly more efficient than the "full" `libdivide_128_div_64_to_64`, using its slow path, which costs two 64-bit divisions plus a bunch of additional stuff). Some processors don't care as much about a non-zero upper half of the dividend though.

This trick works because 2<sup>64</sup> is definitely greater than `n`, so we can subtract `n` from it once, then we get 2<sup>64</sup>-n which is equal to `-n` computed modulo 2<sup>64</sup> (arithmetic on uint64_t is done modulo 2<sup>64</sup>). We can't just put `-n` into the high part of the dividend because then the quotient becomes too large and the division faults, but a dedicated 128-bit by 64-bit *remainder* operation (as opposed to a division that also produces a remainder as a by-product) could support that. So `-n % n` it is.

The `_udiv128` intrinsic could be replaced with a call to `libdivide_128_div_64_to_64` to support other platforms.

It seems plausible to me (given the special nature of this case) that there are more tricks, but I don't know them and couldn't find them. A common recommendation that I encountered was to use exponentiation by squaring, but if taken literally that would first take 6 steps just to get to `-n % n` (we may as well start with that and then do only *one* square), and doesn't solve the biggest problem: how to do what `_udiv128` does without `_udiv128`. Squaring `-n % n` and then reducing it mod `n` doesn't seem any better to me than multiplying `-n % n` by 2<sup>64</sup> and reducing it mod `n`, it just costs an extra multiplication (with 128-bit output) and then leaves us with an equally annoying problem.